# check all checkboxes nextUntil

Tags: jquery, html

Hello I want to do the following.

I've got a list with checkboxes like this:

```
<ul>
  <li class="omzet_first"><input type="checkbox" name="omzet" id="12" value="12" alt="Opbrengsten" checked="checked">Opbrengsten</li>
  <li class="omzet_second"><input type="checkbox" name="omzet" id="13" value="13" alt="Netto Omzet">Netto Omzet</li>
  <li class="omzet_second"><input type="checkbox" name="omzet" id="14" value="14" alt="Overige Opbrengsten">Overige Opbrengsten</li>
  <li class="omzet_first"><input type="checkbox" name="omzet" id="15" value="15" alt="Kosten van grond-en Hulpstoffen / Uitbesteed werk">Kosten van grond-en Hulpstoffen / U</li>
  <li class="omzet_second"><input type="checkbox" name="omzet" id="16" value="16" alt="Inkoopprijs van de verkopen">Inkoopprijs van de verkopen</li>
  <li class="omzet_second"><input type="checkbox" name="omzet" id="17" value="17" alt="Kosten uitbesteed werk">Kosten uitbesteed werk</li>
  <li class="omzet_first"><input type="checkbox" name="omzet" id="18" value="18" alt="Personeelskosten">Personeelskosten</li>
  <li class="omzet_second"><input type="checkbox" name="omzet" id="19" value="19" alt="Lonen &amp; Salarissen">Lonen &amp; Salarissen</li>
  <li class="omzet_second"><input type="checkbox" name="omzet" id="20" value="20" alt="Sociale lasen">Sociale lasen</li>
  <li class="omzet_second"><input type="checkbox" name="omzet" id="21" value="21" alt="Pensioen lasten">Pensioen lasten</li>
</ul>
```

When a checkbox in the li with class omzet_first is checked I want to check all next checkboxes in the li with class omzet_second until the next li.omzet_first.

I tried this but that didnt work

```
$('.omzet_first input:checked').each(function() {
    $(this).nextUntil(".omzet_first", ".omzet_second input:checkbox").prop("checked", true);
});
```

Any suggestions how to do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Inside your event handler, `this` is the checkbox. You have to navigate the DOM tree appropriately (move up to its `.omzet_first` parent before seeking siblings, then move down). Also note that you should use the selector `.omzet_first` with `nextUntil` as well.

```
$('.omzet_first input:checked').each(function() {
    $(this).closest(".omzet_first")
           .nextUntil(".omzet_first")
           .find("input:checkbox")
           .prop("checked", true);
});
```

Comment: This will only bind the event handler to checkboxes that were checked initially. (Also, `this.checked` is (arguably) easier to read but definitely more efficient than `$(this).prop("checked")`.)

Comment: @nnnnnn: For some reason I mentally missed the `:checked` part. It makes sense now, edited the code to reflect.

Answer (score 3):

Your `.each()` loop on elements selected with `:checked` processes any of the checkboxes that are checked *at the time that code runs* - it doesn't respond to a user clicking on the boxes.

If the idea is to respond to the user's clicks you need to to handle that event:

```
$('.omzet_first input[type="checkbox"]').click(function() {
    $(this).parent().nextUntil(".omzet_first")
           .find('input[type="checkbox"]').prop("checked", this.checked);
});
```

To explain that code: when one of the `omzet_first` checkboxes is clicked find its parent (the li), then select all of the parent's sibling up until the next `omzet_first`, then find the child checkboxes within those lis and set their `checked` property. (If the li was not the immediate parent of the input you'd use `$(this).closest(".omzet_first")` instead of `$(this).parent()`.)

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/498vw/